# Commit is in git tree, but does not appeared to be applied to code

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-commit

So I'm trying to figure out a weird issue where a commit was made, merged into our master branch, but then in the following commit the code tied to that commit appears to just disappear. The commit hash is `4516ce019` and on [github](https://github.com/qtumproject/qtum/commits/master?after=5a84ee02e6e948d4222fe3953d97568ee8d692d8+349) the commit is still on the tree, as well as on my local git branch. Excerpt from git log on the master branch:

```
commit 02659934ce32a4e700e1a7116685933e40a58b7f
Author: Jordan Earls <earlz@earlz.net>
Date:   Thu Jun 29 18:50:22 2017 -0400

    Add RPC commands gethexaddress and fromhexaddress

    These RPC commands can be used to convert to and from base58 addressses
    to hex addresses as used in smart contracts

commit 2c15f54789ab4f4e6d3b735aa6849111b5c9299d
Merge: 14c08352c 4516ce019
Author: qtum-neil <neil@qtum.org>
Date:   Wed Jun 28 22:52:20 2017 +0000

    Merge pull request #213 from qtumproject/earlz/add-block-author

    Change block author to be 2nd vout/2nd tx for PoS
```

If you look at [git blame](https://github.com/qtumproject/qtum/blame/2c15f54789ab4f4e6d3b735aa6849111b5c9299d/src/validation.cpp#L2093) on the commit itself, things seem correct, the code is there. However, the commit that follows it on the master branch has a completely different [git blame](https://github.com/qtumproject/qtum/blame/ed22562236c7c7517b717f0c131ad30f712eaa4d/src/validation.cpp#L2093) as if the commit never existed. (saying that code was modified 5 months ago, rather than 2 months ago).

What exactly happened here? I have a feeling it's a merge conflict gone bad, but even that would show up in the recent merges and/or git blame. I'm not able to reproduce this, and we have never force-pushed to this branch after this commit (we did before when we were setting things up).

Does anyone have any guidance on how this is possible, and how to pinpoint exactly where things went wrong? This issue introduced a minor security vulnerability in our codebase and so it's important to understand why this happened; the fix of course is to just trivially do a cherry-pick to pull this commit back in.

EDIT: Using `git fsck --unreachable --no-reflog` reveals no orphaned commits, so my only hunch of a merge leaving the commit behind appears to not be the case

Comment: Parent of 0265 is a633

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like [2c15f54](https://github.com/qtumproject/qtum/commit/2c15f54) (your original PR) and [ed22562](https://github.com/qtumproject/qtum/commit/ed22562) (the commit you linked as the "following commit on master") aren't actually on the same branch. Those two commits didn't get merged together until [e4998dc](https://github.com/qtumproject/qtum/commit/e4998dc), where it's clear that your original changes were removed by the merge. It isn't clear to me why that happened, though.

I used `git log --all --color --graph --pretty='format:%C(red)%h %C(yellow)%d%C(reset) %s  %C(green)%an, %ad%C(reset)' --date=short` to see the graph in a way that shows this.

Comment: Worth mentioning, I think, is that GitHub's attempts to render commit history in a nice, simple, eye-pleasing manner results in pretty lies. In other words, you can't *use* GitHub to figure out what happened; you need real command-line Git, as in this answer.